# Tcl script cannot open file on Linux (Works on Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, tcl

I have a Tcl script that works on Windows. When I run it and pass in file names when prompted, usually with a relative directory path. On Windows the script will take absolute OR relative directory paths ... it works, no problems at all.

On Linux it will NOT work in the same way. It will only work if I spell out the full file path, e.g. `/home/gxuser/input/test.txt` ... It will NOT take relative directory paths like `./input/test.txt`

By "work" I mean it should OPEN the file ... It is there and the permissions are fine.

On Linux the program fails with the following error:

```
   couldn't open "./input/test.txt": no such file or directory
       while executing
   "open $upload r"
```

The offending line in the code is:

```
set infile [open $upload r]
```

What am I doing wrong? I presume, I have overlooked some nuance of the Tcl language, and assumed it should recognize relative paths.

Relevant information:

```
% puts $tcl_version
8.4
% info patchlevel
8.4.19
% uname -a
Linux gxengine 2.6.32-60-generic #122-Ubuntu SMP
```

Comment: From the directory where you run the script, can you do this? `cat ./input/test.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that a function you call is changing the current working directory. There is no way to tell which one that could be without inspecting the code, but you can check if this is the case by displaying `[pwd]` before calling `open`.

Another way things could go wrong is by the script being started in different ways from Unix and Windows - e.g. by shortcut on Windows and from the command line off the `PATH` on Unix.

Comment: Obvious typo ./input/test.txt

Comment: The behavior of the script is different on different platforms. The script remains the same except for the she-bang change. I could add a [pwd] before the open, but that why would the behavior be different on different platforms.

Comment: @ZenMatic There are many reasons why behavior could be different. My prime suspect would be that the way the script is started differs. For example, on Windows it might be started using a shortcut, and on Unix it could be on the `PATH` and therefore started from an arbitrary directory. Or, some command invoked by the script might be changing the CWD in a platform-specific way. It is hard to tell without more information.

Comment: On Windows I invoke it from Dos (no clicking or short cuts).

On Linux I invoke it from the shell.

I am puzzled, hence I posted this. I will investigate more.

Comment: So I discovered a function was changing the directory. In Windows the pwd likely remains the same but on Linux the pwd is changed. Will look at this some more. Pointers were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have filenames passed in by the user and you can't be sure that code you call won't `cd` under your feet, you're advised to process the filenames into *absolute* filenames as soon as possible in your script, possibly even before any `package require` or `source` calls.

This is actually easy to do.

```
set absoluteFilename [file normalize $userProvidedFilename]
```

As long as this is done before the first `cd` (or `chdir()`/`SetCurrentDirectory()` at the C/C++ level) future changes of directory will not break the path. The script must be prepared to work with absolute filenames, but that's easily done.

---

You can turn a relative path into an absolute path with respect to any arbitrary directory with `file join`:

```
set filename [file join [file normalize $arbitraryLocation] $relativeFilename]
```

(The `file join` is smarter than just inserting a directory separator.)